# jQuery is not defined. And how to solve it

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, undefined, defined

This must be quite trivial, but I tried everything. This is my page: http://www.titabonatsou.gr/big-nothing.html

FYI: It should showcase a slider in the middle of the page. But I still get an error of 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

jQuery is not defined here in my code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var si = $('#gallery-1').royalSlider(
.
.
.
.

.{
```

I read about cases that .htaccess does the damage for forbidding hotlinking or permission to the folder that jquery is are forbidden.

What should I do?

Comment: Your jQuery file is blank: http://www.titabonatsou.gr/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js. Try `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`

Comment: I think all my js files are for some reason blank, do you see that? 
http://www.titabonatsou.gr/js/

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery file is empty. Please redownload it from http://jquery.com/download/ and check if your src for the file is correct

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include jquery library into your page. Put `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` in your `head` tag. In order to check **document ready** you can do like this:

```
$(function(){
  // document ready
});
```

Comment: I just did and still nothing!

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: hljs is not defined big-nothing.html:28   
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'royalSlider' ". Please check it!

Comment: yeah but check this out, here in another server that I uploaded it, it works! What is wrong?? http://www.mysecretathens.gr/tita/big-nothing.html

Comment: yeah but in the second server the slider works as you can see.

Comment: Sorry sorry! Because you have two version of jquery in current server. Let remove one of them: jquery-1.8.3.min.js and jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: Also you have invalid jquery.royalslider.min.js file or path in current server. http://www.titabonatsou.gr/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js. It's blank. But here http://www.mysecretathens.gr/tita/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js is ok.

Comment: All files are blank here for some reason: http://www.titabonatsou.gr/js/

I deleted the second version of jquery but still the same!

Comment: Try to use this "http://mysecretathens.gr/tita/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js" for current server. It's important to solve "Object [object Object] has no method 'royalSlider'" error.

Comment: WOW!

that did the trick, it works now! But how can I add it in the actual server? I dont understand why it didnt work :/

Comment: What's different between "/tita/js/" and "/js/"? Make sure your path is ok?

Answer (score 0):

the code you enter can work only after jquery is loaded in your page, may be you use it before your jquery reference